# Android - How to sync local room database with online mysql database?

Tags: android, android-room

I have created a local room database. Now I want the local database to be synced/uploaded to an online MySQL database.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to download the data from a WS exposing some CRUD API with a  REST client (such as Retrofit 2).
After that you can update your local database through Room Dao.

You can't keep *synced* the online MySQL with your local DB just with some configuration. Room provides live updates from local DB to the upper application layers.

Everything about downloading remote data must be manually implemented and managed.

When i talked about WS exposing CRUD API, i was talking about some SOA application interfacing with the MySQL DB.

Comment: Best would be to have a WS that exposes diffs since a timestamp. Or indeed you just download it all after you checked something that marked the remote DB has updated.